# Is it okay to use /tmp on macOS?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Normally I would use `NSTemporaryDirectory`, however, a tool that I'm using has some strict path length limits, and the directory path returned by `NSTemporaryDirectory` is too long. Is it fine to put things directly in `/tmp`, using `NSUUID` to generate a filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what the docs have to say about it:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/RaceConditions.html

"If at all possible, avoid creating temporary files in a shared directory, such as /tmp, or in directories owned by the user. If anyone else has access to your temporary file, they can modify its content, change its ownership or mode, or replace it with a hard or symbolic link. It’s much safer to either not use a temporary file at all (use some other form of interprocess communication) or keep temporary files in a directory you create and to which only your process (acting as your user) has access.

If your file must be in a shared directory, give it a unique (and randomly generated) filename (you can use the C function mkstemp to do this), and never close and reopen the file. If you close such a file, an attacker can potentially find it and replace it before you reopen it.

Here are some public directories that you can use:

...

/tmp

This directory is used for general shared temporary storage. It is cleared out each time the system starts up.

...

For maximum security, you should always create temporary subdirectories within these directories, set appropriate permissions on those subdirectories, and then write files into those subdirectories."

So, it's discouraged, but if you have no other choice, it looks like you'll be okay, with some security caveats.

There is an exception, though; if your app is sandboxed, `/tmp` will not be accessible: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html

Comment: Thanks, I think in my case (a unit test) the security concerns aren't a big enough deal to matter (and, uh, it doesn't work with the long path, so...).